# How to query "LastName, FirstName" from "FirstName LastName" when there may be middle initials?

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

Field contains first and last names.

```
PERSON:
Bob Franklin
Gene Smith
Roy G. Biv
```

I am trying to create a query that puts the last name first, then a comma, then the first name. That part is not a problem. The problem I am having is with Roy G. Biv. Instead of returning his last name, I am getting G. Biv. I wrote a separate query that returns the last name correctly, but I don’t know how to implement the two together.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PERSON, SUBSTR(PERSON,INSTR(PERSON,' ')+1)|| ', '|| substr(person,1,INSTR(person,' ') -1) AS PERSONS
FROM LEDGER
```

This returns:

```
Franklin, Bob
Smith, Gene
G. Biv, Roy
```

This query gives me the results I want from the name with the middle initial:

```
select distinct person, SUBSTR(PERSON,INSTR(PERSON,'.')+1)
from ledger
where person like '%BIV'
```

Returns:

```
Biv
```

What is the best way to combine these? I am really new with SQL, go easy on me! Thanks!

Comment: It would be so much easier to start out with separate names..

Comment: I agree. It's for an assignment.

Comment: Also consider that some people have names with spaces, eg. Mary Kate.

Comment: Lasts names can also have spaces, e.g. Jean Claude van Damme ... you should clearly spell out what the types of data there are here.

Comment: Normalize the database or simply make 2 fields for `FNAME` and `LNAME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the position of the space counting backwards. Check the documentation for INSTR [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564):

```
SELECT DISTINCT PERSON, SUBSTR(PERSON,INSTR(PERSON,' ',-1,1)+1)|| ', '|| substr(person,1,INSTR(person,' ') -1) AS PERSONS
FROM LEDGER
```

Quote from the documentation:

> **Example 7-128 Using Character Position to Search Backward to Find the
>   Position of a Substring**
>
> In this next example, the function counts backward from the last
>   character to the third character from the end, which is the first "o"
>   in "Floor". The function then searches backward for the second
>   occurrence of "or", and finds that this second occurrence begins with
>   the second character in the search string.
>
> ```
> SHOW INSTR('Corporate Floor','or', -3, 2) 
> 2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

usually names separated by space, so it is easier to use substring_index:

```
SELECT 
  substring_index(PERSON, ' ', 1) AS first_name,
  substring_index(PERSON, ' ',-1) AS last_name
FRON ledger
```

And then if you want to re-format as 'last_name, first_name':

```
SELECT concat(
  substring_index(PERSON, ' ',-1),
  ', ',
  substring_index(PERSON, ' ', 1)
) AS full_name
FRON ledger
```

I have been designing user table for years using first_name, last_name, and sometimes middle_name or other_names.

And I find nearly all times use full name. So if you are most times using full names, one field is actually better.

Comment: **(1)** The OP is clearly using Oracle and not MySQL (`|| ', '||`) **(2)** Saving name in a single field is a really bad advice. It is much more complex to split than to concatenate and you can never be 100% sure how to split it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PERSON, ' ',-1),', ' ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(PERSON, ' ',1)) FROM LEDGER
```

Comment: The OP is clearly using Oracle and not MySQL (`|| ', '||`)

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle** solution

```
select  regexp_replace (person,'(\S+)(\s+\S+)?\s+(\S+)','\3, \1') as persons
from    ledger
```

---

```
+----------------+
|    PERSONS     |
+----------------+
|  Franklin, Bob |
|  Smith, Gene   |
|  Biv, Roy      |
+----------------+
```

---

```
\s - A whitespace character.
\S - A non-whitespace character.
+  - Matches one or more occurrences
?  - Matches zero or one occurrence
```

[REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm#SQLRF06302)
[Oracle Regular Expression Support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_posix.htm#SQLRF020)

Answer (score 0):

### You can Use this

```
substr(PERSON,INSTR(PERSON,' ', -1) )||', '|| substr(PERSON,1,INSTR(PERSON,' ', -1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly below mentioned select statement.

```
select substr(PERSON,instr(PERSON,' ',-1))||', '||substr(PERSON,instr(PERSON,' ',1),instr(PERSON,' ',-1)-instr(PERSON,' ',1))||' '||substr(PERSON,0,instr(PERSON,' ',1)) from ledger;
```

Or else club it all in with clause and call it from another select clause which will look simple and easy like below:

```
with temp_ledger as (
select substr(PERSON,instr(PERSON,' ',-1)) as l_name ,substr(PERSON,instr(PERSON,' ',1),instr(PERSON,' ',-1)-instr(PERSON,' ',1)) as m_name, substr(PERSON,0,instr(PERSON,' ',1)) as f_name from ledger )

select l_name||', '||m_name||' '||f_name from temp_ledger;
```

**NOTE: YOU CAN ALSO HANDLE NAME WITH MORE THAN 3 WORDS LIKE** ***"Jean Claude van Damme"***